# Firebase Anonymous Data Security

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

Firebase realtime DB security from a JS app.

I'm allowing a read permission for all password-auth users.
Then, for all other types (only anonymous, per my scheme), I want to allow read for only specific /bundles/.

These are the rules -

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.provider == 'password'", // working!
        "bundles": {
            "$bundle": {
                ".read": "data.child('anonymous').val() == true", // not working
            }
        },
    }
}
```

And /bundles -

```
  "-L-2BbIkAg6J9WPMaJpJ": {
    "anonymous": true,
    "more_data": "data_1"
  },
  "-L-UHBr45eEUHGwsPWqq": {
    "anonymous": false,
    "more_data": "data_2"
  }
```

I expect, when logged-in as anonymous, to see only the first bundle but instead I get an error from FB - "permission_denied at /bundles".

Comment: AFAIK Firebase rules don't filter data. Are you trying to do a query like `ref.child('bundles').once('value')`?

Comment: It can be seen as filtering but I've taken the idea from - https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#structuring_your_rules.
Specifically - 
"rules": {
 "messages": {
  "$message": {
        // only messages from the last ten minutes can be read
        ".read": "data.child('timestamp').val() > (now - 600000)",
  }
 }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.read` fails because you're trying to access the `/bundles` location. If instead you query the specific bundle directly, it will pass:

```
// read denied
ref.child('bundles').once('value')

// read allowed
ref.child(`bundles/-L-2BbIkAg6J9WPMaJpJ`).once('value')
```

You won't be able to filter data through Firebase rules, as stated in [this section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters) of the Firebase docs. I suggest you update the schema and provide a separate node for your anonymous bundles e.g.:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null && auth.provider == 'password'",
    "anonymousBundles": {
      ".read": "auth != null" 
    }
  }
}
```